# Error during Import-SPWeb

Tags: 2010, powershell, spweb

I am trying to exporting from my developing machine which has a backup of the content database, and importing it back in the production farm.

Running:

```
Export-SPWeb -identity http://mysite -Path c:\backup\ps.cmp -includeusersecurity
```

That went fine, and it produced the cmp file without errors.

But trying to import (with Import-SPWeb -Identity ... -Path ...) it in the production server, I got an error after awhile:

```
[20.09.2013 14:43:25] FatalError: The element 'Field' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: any element in namespace '##any'.
[20.09.2013 14:43:25] Debug:    at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadOuterXml()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
```

Anyone got some tips of how I can import this ?

Comment: What is the exact version of your dev farm and of your prod farm?

Comment: What do you mean by exact? I got SP2010 with SP1 on both of the farms.

Comment: You need to make sure both are the exact same build.  You can find this at the top of the page in `Central Administration - System Settings - Manage servers in farm`.

Comment: @DaveWise is correct, this looks like a version mis-match error. If you dont have different bits installed (hotfixed,etc), check to be sure one of your farms didn't have a failed or partial upgrade.

Comment: I'll try to update the destination farm with the same cumulative update as the source farm and see if it works.
Source farm: 14.0.6134.5000
Destination farm: 14.0.6123.5000